# While indexing, Solr returns 400 Status Bad Request when integer fieldtype is left empty

Tags: php, search, solr, lucene

In my Solr schema.xml, I have an integer field and text_general field

```
<field name="popularity" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="priority" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

When I try to index following data onto Solr, I get "400" Status: Bad Request

```
    <add>
        <doc>
            <field name="popularity"></field>
            <field name="id">id_001</field>
            <field name="priority">10</field>
        </doc>
    </add>
```

While it works well when I index following data:

```
    <add>
        <doc>
            <field name="popularity">5</field>
            <field name="id">id_002</field>
            <field name="priority"></field>
        </doc>
    </add>
```

So does that mean integer field can not be empty, while text_general can be?

I am using SolrPHPClient to index data. http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/

Comment: Yes. Why is it important? Just set priority to 0 if empty.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I am doing now. But I wasn't sure if I am doing anything wrong, or is it Solr's usual behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it also valid to not use a field that you don't want to set, so something like:

```
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name="id">id_001</field>
        <field name="priority">10</field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniell, I entirely forgot about that. I was trying to import input feed as it is. I can definitely get rid of empty fields. I tested, and it works well.

Comment: @AujasviChitkara You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. This is also a great common question to have answered here. And I was worried about my triple negatives in the answer.

Comment: @Daniell, Hahaha... they negated each other :)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, just go to solr admin page and reload your core admin, then the error's gone